# NW.js Run flash back

Tags: nw.js

Today I visit the local system in the operation of NW.js, during the operation of flash back, from the new operation there is no problem. Do you know why? Or how to see this log?

Comment: This is an extremely unclear question. "there is no problem" so what are you asking? What is the question? "Or how to see this log" Which log?

Comment: @underscore_d Occasionally it will flash back, re-run the same operation, delete the problem again. So I want to know his running log and I want to figure out how this problem happened

Comment: Oh, that's a much clearer explanation. You could [edit] the title and post to include that better wording. :)

Comment: @underscore_d ok!